# confusion over how to show that f is continuous.

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

Okay , I'm just going to write down exactly what my book says and then ask my question.

"Define the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1+x_2$. Prove that $f$ is continuous, where the distance function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is either $d$ or $d'$ ."

And then in the book, $d$ and $d'$ have been previously defined as

$$d((x_1, x_2, ..., x_n),(y_1,y_2,..., y_n))= \max\{|x_i-y_i|\}, (x_1,x_2,...,x_n), (y_1,y_2,...,y_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$$ (for $1\leq i\leq n$)

and $d'$ is the good old standard Euclidian distance function.

So my problem is that I'm confused about the distance function I'm supposed to use on $R$, seeing as there isn't one defined. Does this work no matter what the distance function on $R$ is, or is there some assumed distance function that I'm supposed to use? Like for example, $$|f(x_1,x_2)-f(a_1,a_2)|$$
?

EDIT: So d is supposed to mean this: Take two points and match each coordinate in one point to its counterpoint in the other coordinate. Then, find the magnitude of the difference between each pair of coordinates. The largest such magnitude is the distance between x and y.

EDIT: The book I am using is "Introduction to Topology" by Bert Mendelson.

Comment: That's a perfectly reasonable question.  In the absence of specification, you usually can take $d(x,y) = | x - y|$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Seems like this is a question about the text itself, but the text is missing...

Comment: I don't understand what $\max\{|x_i,y_i|\}$ is. Even ignoring the fact $i$ a free variable, what's $x_i, y_i$ supposed to denote? And the absolute value of this entity?

Comment: What is meant is probably $d(x,y)=\max_i |x_i-y_i|$. @GitGud

Comment: yes, you're right. That's what I meant.